# Why does my program not execute a perl file

Tags: command-line, paths, perl

I have a perl file name make_html.pl which works on a module named API::PDF2 ([link](http://search.cpan.org/~ssimms/PDF-API2-2.022/lib/PDF/API2.pm)) I downloaded it installed it and I think I set the path wrong.  my @INC has the values

```
Built under linux
  Compiled at Feb  4 2014 22:52:09
  %ENV:
    PERL5LIB="/home/lib-11//Downloads/mirdeep2/lib/PDF:/home/lib-11//Downloads/mirdeep2/lib/PDF"
  @INC:
    /home/lib-11//Downloads/mirdeep2/lib/PDF
    /home/lib-11//Downloads/mirdeep2/lib/PDF
    /etc/perl
    /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2
    /usr/lib/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    /usr/lib/perl/5.14
    /usr/share/perl/5.14
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl
.
```

When I run make_html.pl the error I get is

```
Can't locate PDF/API2.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/lib-11//Downloads/mirdeep2/lib/PDF /home/lib-11//Downloads/mirdeep2/lib/PDF /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /home/lib-11/Downloads/mirdeep2/make_html.pl line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/lib-11/Downloads/mirdeep2/make_html.pl line 9
```

How do I take out all the repeating paths. I know where I installed the module but I am unsure as to which part of the module I need to extend the path to. There are 3 - 4 folders inside the main module folder. I am just a beginner in linux so use simple terms please. I use Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

**EDIT**

I just noticed an error in the path where I have inserted two forward slashes between lib-11 and Downloads in the path. But how do I rectify the error now?

Comment: Try `export PERL5LIB="/home/lib-11/Downloads/mirdeep2/lib/PDF"`. If necessary, add this command to `.bashrc`.

Comment: @Jos same error after adding the sentence to bashrc

Comment: Ah, perhaps you need to remove the /PDF from the end of the PERL5LIB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the module is called PDF::API2, PDF will be a directory searched by Perl under one of the directories contained in @INC.

In other words and considering the information you give, if you have `/home/lib-11/Downloads/mirdeep2/lib/PDF` in your @INC, it will search the PDF directory ( and possibly a PDF.pm module file) below this directory.

You have to remove the `PDF` part from your path and it should find your library:

```
/home/lib-11/Downloads/mirdeep2/lib/
```

Comment: What command do I use to change or edit @INC. It doesn't seem to change